# Encontrar lugares próximos a uma determinada coordenada

Tags: javascript, html5, geolocalização

Gostaria de encontrar locais próximos a uma determinada coordenada geográfica.

Tenho uma base de dados com uma lista de pontos de referência e suas respectivas coordenadas.

Ex.:

```
var points = [
  ['cristo redentor', '111111', '222222']
  ['parque do ibirapuera', '111111', '222222']
  ['museu do ipiranga', '111111', '222222']
  ['av paulista', '111111', '222222']
]
```

Quando o usuário buscar por um ponto de referência, eu gostaria de encontrar todos os outros pontos que estejam perto daquela coordenada escolhida.

Comment: @rLinhares o contexto é o mesmo mas são linguagens distintas! :(

Comment: blz. Estou tentando encontrar algo, mas até agora nada muito útil

Comment: muito obrigado @rLinhares :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue uma função para calcular a distância em KM, caso precise da distancia em Milhas, basta utilizar a outra variável já declarada na última multiplicação da saída do método.

Segue exemplo de chamada do código também.
  Latitude 1:  -23.5415,
  Longitude 1: -46.5786, 
  Latitude 2: -22.1410, 
  Longitude 2: -46.0216

```js
function btnCalcular() {
        var result = CalcularDistancia(
            $("#latitude1").val(),
            $("#longitude1").val(),
            $("#latitude2").val(),
            $("#longitude2").val()
            );

        alert(result);
};
        
function CalcularDistancia(
Latitude1 ,
Longitude1 ,
Latitude2 ,
Longitude2
)
{
<!-- CONSTANTES -->
var RaioTerraEmML = 3963.1
var RaioTerraEmKM = 6377.99121
var PI  = Math.PI;

<!-- RAIO  -->
var lat1Radians ;
var long1Radians ;
var lat2Radians ;
var long2Radians ;

 lat1Radians = Latitude1 * PI / 180;
 long1Radians = Longitude1 * PI / 180;
 lat2Radians = Latitude2 * PI / 180;
 long2Radians = Longitude2 * PI / 180;

return Math.acos(
Math.cos(lat1Radians) * Math.cos(long1Radians) * Math.cos(lat2Radians) * Math.cos(long2Radians) + 
Math.cos(lat1Radians) * Math.sin(long1Radians) * Math.cos(lat2Radians) * Math.sin(long2Radians) + 
Math.sin(lat1Radians) * Math.sin(lat2Radians)
) * RaioTerraEmKM;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>latitude1 </label><input type="text" id="latitude1" value="" />
    <label>longitude1 </label><input type="text" id="longitude1" value="" />
    <label>latitude2 </label><input type="text" id="latitude2" value="" />
    <label>longitude2 </label><input type="text" id="longitude2" value="" />

    <input type="button" name="btnCalcular" onclick="btnCalcular()" value="Calcular" />
```

Comment: Valeu @Alexandre muito obrigado!